# Check if WINWORD.EXE Process is Running?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I've got a C# Winforms Application that processes queried data into Mail Merge documents. How can I check on application start-up to see if current user has a Microsoft Word Instance Open, and if so, alert them to close before proceeding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("winword.exe");
if (processes.Length == 0)
//not running
else
//running
```

Comment: My intellisense doesn't give me an option for `Process`?

Comment: add :
using System.Diagnostics;

Comment: **Remove** the `.exe` part to get proper results.

Comment: winword.exe is correct process name.  You check this also in Task Manager

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working. processes always has a length of 0, whether I have a word process open or not.

Comment: @Idle_Mind, thanks, removing the `.exe` did the trick it seems!

Comment: @Idle_Mind Yes, it's actually just winword.  Strange this, as it shows as winword.exe in task manager.  Anyway, it works :)

Comment: Right..it always expects the executable name, without the `.exe` part, and without any kind of path.

Comment: @Idle_Mind, semi-related note: Is there a way for me to close all winword processes? (This would be in event of an exception thrown during mail merge processing to prevent users from having an invisible instance of word open)

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic Yes, you can call process.Close()

Comment: for all processes do -
foreach (var process in processes)
        {
            process.Close();
        }

Comment: Process.CloseMainWindow() might be what you're looking for.  If that puts up a prompt, you could also try the harsher Process.Kill().

Answer (score 3):

Use LINQ `Any`:

```
var isRunning = Process.GetProcessesByName("winword").Any();
```

Comment: My intellisense doesn't give me an option for `Process`?